# How to set php chart lite library?

Tags: php

I am using wamp server. In local disk c there is wamp folder than wwww folder this is default setting of wamp. Now i have created a folder for my website named chart. chart folder contain 
index.php which contain my code. there is also a php chart lite library in chart folder. I am creating chart using this library. But it is not working. Can anybody tell me how to configure conf.php and other files to run this code Below is the path and code:-

C:\wamp\www\chart this folder contains index file and phpChart_Lite folder.

```
<?php
require_once("phpChart_Lite\conf.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>phpChart - Basic Chart</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array(11, 9, 5, 12, 14)),'basic_chart');
$pc->draw();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you add correctly require_once("phpChart_Lite\conf.php");

Comment: That is what i exactly want how to set conf.php. I have added the whole detail of my files and code.

Answer (score 0):

Your require_once filepath appears correct, maybe it's a matter of file permissions? I used chmod 755. I am also struggling with phpChart, while my index file is able to access conf.php, it seems that conf.php has its own issues too, which I can't seem to resolve as I just followed documentation. Another php chart library you might want to consider is libchart, I've had more success with it.